# @WebFilter and FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() -> Nullpointer

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

In my application I have a WebFilter. This Webfilter should check a coockie. But the use of FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() gives a Nullpointer exception. How can I solve this?

The WebFilter:

```
@Inject
private CookieManager cm;   

[...]

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if(cm.isDoCheck()){
        cm.doCheck();
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
[...]
```

The CookieManager which does the FacesContext.getCurrentInstance():

```
[...]
private void doCheck(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, Object> cookies = context.getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap();

    Cookie cookie = (Cookie) cookies.get("frontend");
    if(cookie != null){
        setSessionHash(cookie.getValue());
    }
}
[...]
```

`context.getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap();` gives the

```
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FacesContext` is created by `FacesServlet`. Any servlet filter is invoked *before* any servlet. The `FacesContext` is therefore per definition not available in any servlet filter.

As to the concrete functional requirement of grabbing the request cookies, you also seem to have completely missed the fact that `FacesContext` is a [facade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297) of among others the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse`. The methods of `ExternalContext` all delegate under the covers to `ServletRequest`/`ServletResponse` methods (this is clearly mentioned in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html), for example [`getRequestCookieMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestCookieMap%28%29)). The cookie methods you need is just readily available via `ServletRequest` argument of the `doFilter()` method.

```
HttpServletRequest hsr = (HttpServletRequest) request;
Cookie[] cookies = hsr.getCookies();
// Loop over cookies to find the one matching the name.
```

Noted should be that there is a [hack/workaround](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingTheFacesContextInsideHttpServletOrFilter) available to create `FacesContext` in the filter yourself based on `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` variables, but this makes after all no utter sense if the information is readily available in those variables themselves.

I suggest to take a little JSF pause and learn basic Servlet API as well. That's basically what JSF is using under the covers (you see, its `FacesServlet` is "just" a servlet). Reading the method descriptions in the `ExternalContext` javadoc should also hint you where exactly in the basic Servlet API all those methods are getting their information from.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. I understand. I will study this basics. At all, the question which raises for me after your answer: What would be the right way to do what I want? I must call this `doCheck()` method also from other methods of my application, not only from the filter. So the approach to use the `ServletRequest` argument of the `doFilter()` method is not suitable for me.

Comment: A filter is the perfect place to check a cookie on a broad range of requests. A filter allows you to change the request destination by simply calling dispatcher.forward() or response.sendRedirect() instead of chain.doFilter(). See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info